# Questions about pushbuttons - through-hole or SMD

Tags: surface-mount, button, through-hole

I am designing an Arduino shield in KiCAD.

I have to have a reset button, so I got [these buttons.](https://www.cableworks.gr/ilektronika/arduino-and-microcontrollers/components-and-ic/buttons/6x6x4.3mm-momentary-tactile-push-button-switch-for-arduino/)

[image]

As you can see, the pins are really long (I extended the pins in one of them.)

How are these buttons used? Are they through hole or SMD components?

I plan on using SMD components.

Comment: You could bend the pins on those switches to convert them to surface-mount.

Comment: @PeterBennettDo you think i can design an smd footpring and solder these on that footprint?

Comment: Well... I know I could, as I've designed footprints for many other things.  You just need to take careful measurements of where the bent switch contacts will tough the board in order to determine where to put the pads, and what size to make them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are through-hole. SMD parts in that size are a bit different. The pins "snap" into the holes to hold the part in position when you design the footprint properly.

(photo from Digikey)

[image]

Comment: What decides how big an SMD part can be? Width of the trace? Epoxy used for binding the copper to substrate? Type of substrate? All of the above? Can a regular paper phenolic PCB hold one of these switches reliably?